# choosing scene based on prop

Tags: react-native, mobx, react-native-router-flux

We're using `mobx` along with `react-native-router-flux`. I want to load a different route based on a value from a `mobx` store. I'm trying to understand how to do this. So I have this from my store

`const { authenticated, profile: { role } } = stores.authStore;`

I pass the role as a prop to `<PrivateRouter role={role} />`. I want to select a `<Scene>` based on the value of `role`. All of this takes place in the `App.js` file. Any ideas on how I would do this? I'm new to both mobx and RNRF, so I'm not clear on how to accomplish this. Am I thinking correctly about this use case?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it resolved. So here's the solution in case someone encounters the same issue.

The problem was that `profile` is not exposed until the user is authenticated. So the app couldn't find it. The solution is as follows:

```
const render =
      authenticated === undefined ? (
        <LoadingScreen />
      ) : authenticated === true ? (
        stores.authStore.profile.role === 'USER' ? (
          <home />
        ) : (
          <TrainerHome />
        )
      ) : (
        <PublicRouter />
      );
    return (
      <Root>
        <Provider {...stores}>{render}</Provider>
      </Root>
    );
```

Hope this provides help for future issues.